# How to implement two QuerySets in .html

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm new to Django and trying to understand how it works.
Basically, I'm building this simple Blog and I have one Question regarding the implementation of the QuerySets in my `.html` file.

This is how my code looks like:

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
        [...]

class Highlight(models.Model):
        [...]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .models import Highlight

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def highlight_list(request):
    highlights = Highlight.objects.all
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'highlights': highlights})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
path('', views.highlight_list, name='highlight_list'),
]
```

**post_list.html**

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post }}
{% endfor %}

{% for highlight in highlights %}
{{ highlight }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is, it only shows the objects from the class Post.
Is it somehow possible to include both QuerySets from both classes?
If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if there is any `Highlight` objects stored in DB?

Answer (score 1):

There is so many approaches to achieve this. I mention one

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    highlights = Highlight.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'highlights':highlights})
```

Then you can access both `highlights` and `posts` in `post_list.html`

Comment: Yes that's the one I used. Thank you :) !

Comment: Hey, @nonskill, you should mark this as the answer for future seekers and so shafik can get credit :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're hitting the url `127.0.0.1:8000`, the first url that is getting matched is `path('', views.post_list, name='post_list')` this one because in your `urls.py` this is your first url. When there's a multiple match, always the first one will always be called.

Therefore, the view function, that is getting called is the `post_list`.

In your `post_list` you are only retrieving Post objects and that's why when you're returning to your `html` only the post objects are getting rendered and there are no `highlight` objects.

That's why you can't find any `highlight` objects in your front end.

You can do the following:

```
def post_response_with_highlight(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all
    highlights = Highlight.objects.all
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'highlights': highlights
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'context': context})
```

And now in your 'html' you can get both the `posts` and the `highlights`

Answer (score 1):

Already managed it, thanks!
If anyone else has the problem, here is the solution:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .models import Highlight

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all
    highlights = Highlight.objects.all
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'highlights': highlights})
```